# Contour lines from point shape attribute

Tags: grass-gis, interpolation, contour

I have a point shapefile and one of the attribute refers to the altitude. 
Is is possible to obtain a contour lines shapefile in GRASS?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing 16032 was referring to the GRASS modules in QGIS.

First: [Interpolation](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.surf.idw.html)
Then: [Contours](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/r.contour.html)

Comment: Consider also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation  --> "Interpolating from vector points"

Answer (score 0):

In Qgis:
Raster>Grid/Interpolation
then
Raster > Extraction > Contour

Comment: That's great! Isn't a similar command in grass?