# Draw lake isobaths having depth points and coast line

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

For some lakes, I have a line shapefile representing the coast line and some points with many information, among which depth (in meters). Is there a way to draw an isobath linking every point with the same depth, but following the coast line?
I work mainly with QGIS and GRASS and I have already tried the QGIS Contour plugin, but the result isn't good.
Here a couple of images of the dataset, the first showing only the coast line and the second showing coast line and points at 1.5 m depth.
[image: Varese lake coast line]
[image: Coast line and depth points]

Comment: The points will naturally "follow the coastline"

Answer (score 1):

If you also have more depths points I would make a TIN interpolation (Raster > Interpolation), creating a raster grid of the lake. Converting the raster to vector (Raster > Conversion > Polygonize) will give you the contour as a vector line or polygon. If I have a limited number of points, I would stick with the QGIS Contour plugin. The lines generated by the Contour plugin can be smoothed with the Generalizer plugin.

Comment: Having just few points (from 0.5 to 4.5 m) I chose the second option, but I can't get a satisfying polygon, I don't know how to make the polygon borders follow the lake borders

Comment: You could add a lot of artificial points where there are a hole in the dataset.

Comment: I tried another way with better results, as indicated [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60085/contour-lines-from-point-shape-attribute): interpolation and contour lines from interpolated model.